# How my model Laravel could be return me all prices for each item only last date in hasMany?

Tags: laravel, model, eloquent, has-many

I have 2 models(market,price_item), i want return last prices for each item (model 2) for 1 market (model 1).

i have in my model 1:

```
    public function prices()
{
    return $this->hasMany(MarketPrices::class, self::IDMarket)->groupBy(['item']);
}
```

This solution give me price for each item but not last price. 
I tried orderBydesc but not work.

Thanks you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all this is not how you create a relation
A "one-to-many" relationship is used to define relationships where a single model owns any amount of other models. For example, a blog post may have an infinite number of comments. Like all other Eloquent relationships, one-to-many relationships are defined by placing a function on your Eloquent model:

```
public function prices()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Models/MarketPrices', 'id');
}
```

call it like

```
$price = Yourmodel::find(1);
dd($price->prices); //return the 1 model connected
```

Comment: Thanks. With your help i understand my mistake.